# Powershell changes to registry not appearing on GUI

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to automate a lot of the administrative changes needed before installing a piece of software my whole office uses.  This is on Windows 2012 R2.  One of the changes is to disable automatic updates of the root certificate, and disallowing issuer certificates to be retrieved during path validation.

After finding these settings in HKCU: and using the `set-itemproperty` `cmdlet`, `Powershell` confirms that I've made the changes (with `get-itemproperty`).  This is also confirmed on `regedit`.  However, when checking the GUI in

> admin tools>local security policy>public key policies>certificate path validation settings>network retrieval tab.

I find no changes to the settings.  I've tried restarting `powershell`, refreshing admin tools, etc. to no avail.  I've also tried `compare-object` on HKCU: before and after making the changes from the GUI, but they're identical.  It's like the GUI is pointing to some other registry/memory location than Powershell and regedit.

The keys I'm editing in `Powershell`/`regedit` are found in:

```
HKCU:\software\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\Group Policy Objects\{BEC8AAFF-2F4D-4C6A-90AF-FB4E455E3385}Machine\software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine
```

Comment: Please give us an indication about which registry key you changed. Keep in mind that the local policy editor adjusts keys in the Policy branch of the registry.

Comment: Good call, I added that in the last paragraph.